# Where to find an exhaustive list of stop words?

Tags: nlp, lexical-analysis, stop-words

Where could I find an exhaustive list of stop words? The one I have is quite short and it seems to be inapplicable to scientific texts. 
I am creating lexical chains to extract key topics from scientific papers. The problem is that words like `based`, `regarding`, etc. should also be considered as stop words as they do not deliver much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also easily add to existing stop word lists. E.g. use the one in the NLTK toolkit:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

and then add whatever you think is missing:

```
stopwords = stopwords.words('english')+["based", "regarding"]
```

The original NLTK list is described [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/corpora/stopwords.zip).

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to find an exhaustive list of stop words because a given word could be considered as a stop word in a given domain but it is an important word in another domain.

you could take a look at some lists of stop words:

http://blog.adlegant.com/how-to-install-nltk-corporastopwords/

http://www.lextek.com/manuals/onix/stopwords1.html

http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords

http://xpo6.com/list-of-english-stop-words/

Comment: Maybe in this case it's more important to check for some domain specific dictionary? (I use WordNet)... I am a newbie in NLP