# What is the right way to use NLTK stopwords?

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words

I'm working on a bag of words project and I want to remove stop words from the NLTK list of stop words. At moment, I'm doing this:

`words.difference_update(set(stopwords.words("english")))`

(words is a set containing all the words in the corpus)

However, when I look at the contents of `stopwords.words("english")` I see words like: "couldn" and "doesn". I assume these are word prefixes for words like "couldn't" and "doesn't" and maybe other words.

So, I assume there is a way to check to see if a word is in the stop words list that is more sophisticated than pure string equality but I can't figure out what it is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can also download the whole corpus [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/packages/corpora/stopwords.zip) and read/ modify it at your leisure. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701305/where-to-find-an-exhaustive-list-of-stop-words/37712453#37712453) goes into how to modify the NLTK list as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's no right way for using stopwords. It depends on what task you want to accomplish. However, based on the information you provided, it seems like NLTK is making an assumption that you're splitting your document by whitespace and punctuations. However, I can make a guess that the stopword list will also contain words such as `could` and `does`. My approach would be to use NLTK's [tokenize](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize) package to create tokens of the corpus first and then running your `difference_update`:

```
words = set(nltk.word_tokenize(document))
```

Note that depending on the tokenization model, the function could split out negative words such as `couldn't` into `['could',"n't"]`. Therefore, if the stopword list doesn't include the `n't` string, you'll have to remove that too from your set.

Another assumption I'm making is that your corpus contains only lower case words.

Hope that helps!

Comment: How do you detect if a token is the second half of a word (aside form looping through the words split on space and the tokens and comparing).

Comment: Sorry, I figured out what you mean. By using tokenize I got tokens that the stopwords list expected.